# How to put a list inside a form from an API in C#

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to find out how to put JSON data extracted from an API inside a Windows Form. I created a class containing this code:

```
namespace ServerList
{
    public class ServerList
    {
        private static async Task API()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var client = httpClient;
            var resp = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/servers");
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(resp);  
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<Sinfo> Response { get; set; }
        public bool Error { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sinfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Online { get; set; }
        public int Players { get; set; }
        public int Queue { get; set; }
        public int Maxplayers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have this data in another form. This is what I've done so far:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sinfo Sinfo = new Sinfo();
    servername.Text = "These servers are online right now:";
    label2.Text = Sinfo.Name + ": " + Sinfo.Players + "/" + Sinfo.Maxplayers + " players in-game. Players in queue: " + Sinfo.Queue;
}
```

How can I set variables for the data in Sinfo? How could I get a list showing all these values inside a Windows Form in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget that you can mark it as accepted.  
If you need more help let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `ListView` to display the data.
Here some example data to get you going.

```
private void CreateMyListView()
{
    // Create a new ListView control.
    ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10,10), new Size(300,200));

    // Set the view to show details.
    listView1.View = View.Details;
                
    // Create some items with values from your `sinfo` object 
    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem($"{Sinfo.Name}", 0);
    ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem($"{Sinfo.Players}", 1);

    // Create columns for the items and subitems.
    // Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column 1", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    //Add the items to the ListView.
    listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{item1,item2});
}
```

I'm using WPF and not WinForms so I'm not sure if the following *string interpolation* `$"{Sinfo.Name}"` also works in WinForms.

Here is the offical documention about [ListView class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=net-5.0) in WinForms.
And [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/working-with-listview-in-C-Sharp/) you find a detailed step by step guide with many examples.